# angularjs получить элемент вызвавший событие

Tags: javascript, angularjs

привет есть div который повторяется

```
<div class="container-client" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-mouseover="over();">
</div>
```

как получить его в контролере и 
как правильно передавать аргумент

```
ng-mouseover="over(item.color);
```

или

```
ng-mouseover="over({{item.color}});
```

item.color это цвет для заднего фона

Answer (score 0):

Правильно вызывать `ng-mouseover="over(item.color);`.

Получить элемент можно через событие:

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    this.clickMe = function(event) {
      console.log(event.srcElement);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.clickMe($event)">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Лучше всего устанавливать цвет заднего фона через **css**.